# How can the JsonProvider be used with URLs requiring authentication?

Tags: http, f#, type-providers, f#-data

I want to do something very similar to what's shown in the [docs for FSharp.Data](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/):

[image]

The URL I'm requesting from though (TFS) requires client authentication. Is there any way I can provide this by propagating my Windows creds? I notice `JsonProvider` has a few other compile-time parameters, but none seem to be in support of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to provide a live URL as a type parameter to `JsonProvider`; you can also provide the filename of a sample file that reflects the structure you expect to see. With that feature, you can do the following steps:

First, log in to the service and save a JSON file that reflects the API you're going to use.

Next, do something like the following:

```
type TfsData = JsonProvider<"/path/to/sample/file.json">
let url = "https://example.com/login/etc"
// Use standard .Net API to log in with your Windows credentials
// Save the results in a variable `jsonResults`
let parsedResults = TfsData.Parse(jsonResults)
printfn "%A" parsedResults.Foo  // At this point, Intellisense should work
```

This is all very generic, of course, since I don't know precisely what you need to do to log in to your service; presumably you already know how to do that. The key is to retrieve the JSON yourself, then use the `.Parse()` method of your provided type to parse it.

Comment: P.S. Same technique works for XmlProvider, HtmlProvider, and so on. Instead of using `.Load(someUrl)`, download the XML/HTML/JSON yourself and then use `.Parse(someDownloadedData)`.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to have it go directly to the API itself rather than needing to hard code a copy of a type spec locally which needs updating whenever the API does, since if the program contains a spec for a type I figure that's not that different to it just containing the code for the types themselves, defeating the point of a type provider. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding their point (I suppose they do provide the translation into the types too).

Anyway, I'll just do this - if I want to get the spec auto-generated I guess I can add a pre-build step to download from the source.